# Lucene: How to perform search on several independent index sets and merge the result?

Tags: java, search, lucene, search-engine

Now I have several Lucene index sets (I call it shards), which indexes different document sets. They are independent, which means I can perform search on each of them without reading others. Then I get a query request. I want to search it over every index set and combine the result to form the final top documents.

I know that when scoring the documents, Lucene needs to know the <**idf**> of every term, and different index sets will give different <**idf**> to the same term (because different index sets hold different document sets). Thus to my understanding, I cannot compare the document score from different index sets directly. Then how should I generate the final result?

An obvious solution would be first merge the index and then perform the search over the big index. However, this is tooo time-consuming for me and thus unacceptable. Anyone has other better solutions?

P.S.: I don't want to use any packages or softwares (like Katta) except Lucene and Hadoop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [MultiReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiReader.html) is what you are looking for.  If you have multiple IndexReaders, say `reader1` and `reader2`:

```
MultiReader multiReader = new MultiReader(reader1, reader2);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(multiReader);
```

Comment: I want to do this in Hadoop mappers and reducers. So how is the cost of open an IndexReader over a GB-level index in a mapper and pass the reader directly to reducer, and then build search over the readers in reducer? Could you provide some clues?

Comment: Generally, opening a new Reader is expensive, and you should keep the same reader around for reuse, reopening it only when necessary.

Comment: Is that possible for me to use IndexReader as Map OutputFormat (in another word, I write a Hadoop writable IndexReader) and reuse it in the following Reduce job? Will that be a good idea?

Comment: In another word, I mean I open a IndexReader to do some job in mapper, and then I serialize it instead of closing it. In the following mappers, I deserialize the IndexReader and reuse it. Is that efficient?

Comment: I don't know much about the Hadoop style of serialization, but unless it's doing some sort of magic, I suspect this would incur greater costs than just opening an IndexReader, if it works at all.  Doesn't seem like serialization of an IndexReader makes a lot of sense, to me.