# Combine multiple Lucene indexes, with docs in same structure, for querying with sorting

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I'm using Lucene Index for indexing of a couple of repositorys in a Java application.
I've 3 indexes that stores documents of the **same structure (fields)**. One contains  approximately 160.000 docs, the second 30.000 and third 40.000.

There is no problem right now with the querying or sorting of result when I'm querying against one at a time. But, **I want to query them all 3 and have the combined result sorted in the specified order**.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16789618/2231632

Comment: Thanks a lot prabugp. This seems to be the answer on my question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [multireader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiReader.html)

```
IndexReader r1= IndexReader.open(...)
IndexReader r2= IndexReader.open(...)
MultiReader multiReader = new MultiReader(r1, r2);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(multiReader);
```

for more details you can see this [example](http://atans.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/java-lucene-search-multi-reader/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out now and will get back to this thread when I've tested it!